# Post request "pending" in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I'm using a Node.js Express framework to upload a file, process it using async.js and render it on a page through a POST request to /design. The user then manipulates the image and can go to their shopping cart by following a POST request to /cart. The upload and processing of the file via /design goes exactly as I want it to, but once the user continues through to /cart, this request stays pending with no outcome.

In more detail:

The user uploads a file, which is then processed, through a POST request to /design:

```
router.post('/design', function(req, res) {

    var file;
    req.session.uuid = sessionHandler.createUuid();


  file = req.files.photo;

    tasks = [

        function fileUpload(cb){

            fileHandler.upload(req.session,file,method,function(fileProperties){
                for(var k in fileProperties) req.session[k]=fileProperties[k];
                cb();
            });

        },
        function setCookies(cb){

            var imgData = {
                S3FilePath: req.session.S3FilePath,
                fullFilePath: req.session.fullFilePath,
                uuid: req.session.uuid,
                S3PreviewPath: req.session.S3PreviewFilePath
            };

            res.cookie('imgData', JSON.stringify(imgData), { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false, encode: String});

            cb();

        }
    ];

    async.series(tasks, (err, results) => {
        if (err){
            console.log('Error:' + err);
        } else{
            console.log('Rendering image');
            res.render('app',{ title : 'Designer' });
            res.end();
        }
    });

});
```

The /design POST request uses the following module to upload and process the file.

```
var upload = function(session,file,callback){

  var fileProperties = {};

  tasks = [
      function createDir(cb){
            mkdirp('./public/uploads/'+session.uuid+'/', function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('directory created');
                    return cb();
                } else{
                    cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        function getFileExtension(cb){
            request.post({
                url:'http://localhost:1652/framer/getextension',
                form: {
                    filePath: file.path
                }
            }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                if (err) console.log(err);
                fileProperties.extension = body;
                return cb();
            });
        },
        function uploadLocal(cb){

            fileProperties.fileName = session.uuid + '.' + fileProperties.extension;
            fileProperties.previewPath = '/uploads/' + session.uuid + '/' + session.uuid + '-preview.' + fileProperties.extension;
            fileProperties.fullFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '/../public/uploads/' + session.uuid + '/' + fileProperties.fileName);
            fs.rename(file.path, fileProperties.fullFilePath, function(err){
                if (err) throw cb(err);
                console.log('file uploaded locally');
                cb();
            });

        },
        function uploadS3(cb){
            request.post({
                url:'http://localhost:1656/s3/put',
                form: {
                    filePath: fileProperties.fullFilePath,
                    fileName: fileProperties.fileName
                }
            }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                if (err) throw cb(err);
                console.log('file uploaded to S3');
                fileProperties.S3FilePath = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/designer/'+fileProperties.fileName;
                return cb();
            }); 
        },
        function generatePreview(cb){
        console.log("Calling preview method");
            request.post({
                url:'http://localhost:1652/framer/preview',
                form: {
                    filePath: fileProperties.fullFilePath,
                    extension: fileProperties.extension,
                    dirName: __dirname,
                    uuid: session.uuid
                }
            }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                if (err) throw cb(err);
                fileProperties.previewFullFilePath = body;
                return cb();
            });
        },
        function uploadPreviewS3(cb){
            request.post({
                url:'http://localhost:1656/s3/put',
                form: {
                    filePath: fileProperties.previewFullFilePath,
                    fileName: session.uuid + '-preview.' + fileProperties.extension
                }
            }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                if (err) throw cb(err);
                console.log('Preview file uploaded to S3');
                fileProperties.S3PreviewFilePath = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/designer/'+session.uuid + '-preview.' + fileProperties.extension;
                return cb();
            }); 
        }
  ];
  async.series(tasks, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('File upload error:' + err);
      } else{
        callback(fileProperties);
      }
  });

};
```

When wanting to go continue to the next page a post request takes the user through to their shopping cart, which I have now shortened to only show a console.log message.

```
router.post('/cart', function (req, res){

    console.log('Go to payment');
    res.end();

});
```

This request starts put continues to stay in "pending" mode in Chrome Developer tools and nothing further happens. After a while the following appears in terminal:

```
POST /cart - - ms - -
```

The other errors that show up during the upload process is a ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error and a MaxListenersExceededWarning error. Unfortunately I can't find anywhere in the code the reason why headers would be sent more than once, unless I haven't used async.js in the correct manner. Secondly, I'm not sure why a MaxListenersExceededWarning error would show up as it's a single POST request.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express-debug/lib/response.js:124:29)
    at finalize (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express-debug/lib/response.js:47:21)
    at toolbar_callback (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express-debug/lib/response.js:99:17)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:412:12)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:455:11)
    at View.render (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
directory created
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express-debug/lib/response.js:124:29)
    at finalize (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express-debug/lib/response.js:47:21)
    at toolbar_callback (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express-debug/lib/response.js:99:17)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:412:12)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:455:11)
    at View.render (/Users/dazzatron/designer/app/frontpage/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
file uploaded locally
file uploaded to S3
Calling preview method
Preview file uploaded to S3
Rendering image
POST /design 200 4516.438 ms - 480447
(node:95893) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 field listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:95893) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 file listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:95893) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:95893) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
POST /cart - - ms - -
```

Any help on why my POST request keeps getting stuck would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe I may have figured out the issue as when I disabled the module express-formidable the requests started passing through.